# How to make .ipa file from react native app

Tags: ios, react-native, react-native-ios

I successfully ran react native app in simulater. But I want to run the app in iPad or iPhone. How can I create .ipa file from react native app I have?

Comment: this sums it pretty much : https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/running-on-device.html#building-your-app-for-production

Comment: I don't want to release in app store. I want to test in my local device first.

Comment: Its not only for releasing to the app store. Its for bundling and archiving the app as an .IPA to be run as release version.

Comment: But if you only want to run the dev version on your phone, open xcode and chose your device as the build target...

Answer (score 3):

According to your comment *"I don't want to release in app store. I want to test in my local device first"*:

1. Open the Xcode-Project inside of the "ios"-Folder with XCode
2. Connect your iPhone per USB with your Mac
3. Select the iPhone instead a "Simulator" in the Dropdown where all Simulators are listed. It should be shown on top if everything worked fine.
4. Launch the App.

[image]
[image]

If you want to test the Release-Mode instead of Debug-Build you have to duplicate the Scheme and select the Build Configuration "Release" under "Run":

[image]

According to your original question "how to create the IPA" you can replace step 4) with this one:

5. XCode -> Mainmenu -> Product -> Archive

This will create a bundle and then you can export the IPA-File to a folder of your choice.

[image]